# Why sprintf appends characters just before char array again?

Tags: c

```
int main () {

  char str1[121];

  char str2[4];
  unsigned char x=255;
  unsigned char y=2;
  memset(str1, 0, 121);
  memset(str2, 0, 4);

  strncpy(str2, "jyot",4);

  sprintf(str1,"%d-%d-%s", x,y,str2);
  printf("%s",str1);

   return(0);
}
```

Why is it printing 255-2-jyot-255-2?? Should sprintf automatically not append null character after writing last char array?

Comment: What happened to `str2` when you used `strncpy`?  Where is `str2` null-terminated?  And doesn't `strncpy` take 3 arguments?

Comment: I can definitely make it work by adding NULL at the end of str2 and allocating one more byte. But I am just curious to know why writing only 4 bytes in sprintf does not work?

Comment: You focused on the wrong thing -- the issue is with `str2`, not with `sprintf`, as the answer below points out.  Second, when tagging languages (even though it's been edited), don't put a C++ tag on code that is C.  There is no way a C++ compiler would have allowed your code to compile, all due to `strncpy` being called with the wrong number of arguments.  C allows this.

Comment: Please be careful with editing questions after receiving answers. It is considered making a "moving target" and largely not apreciated on StackOverflow. It breaks the usefulness of Q/A pairs. Please consider undoing the change and making a new question on the actual code. For the future, please double check that the code you are asking about is actually the code you show in the question. The concept of making a [mcve] is closely related to the problems you can otherwise get. As you have noticed, it does not help you if you get answers about different code.

Answer (score 2):

You are very lucky that your computer did not explode when it had to run this code.

This program is one huge UB. Your `str2` is too short. Even if you copy (using `strncpy` only 4 `char`s the array does not have enough space to accommodate the trailing zero and `strncpy` does not copy the last zero.

Change it to:

```
char str2[5];
strcpy(str2, "jyot");
```

and delete the `memset` calls as they are not needed here.

Do not ignore warnings!!!! And compile using more modern standard which does not allow to call  functions with no prototypes

Comment: @JyotiRajSharma The char array is still too short if it remains at 4.  It needs to be at least 5 characters (where you need room for the terminating null).

Comment: OP has turned the question into a moving target. Because of this (and just maybe for kindness) you might want to review your otherwise good answer.